# How to remove the tripadvisor logo from the wordpress theme?

Tags: themes, menus, templates

Tripadvisor offers a free wordpress theme at [here](http://www.tripadvisor.com/WordPress/TripAdvisor-Map-Theme)

If you go on this page, you'll see the free wordpress theme, and on the navigation bar, there is the trip advisor logo on the right, How can I remove this logo because i have many menu items?? By the way can i remove it not specified nothing as rules and regulation??

Comment: could you post a link to your site? the quickest way would be to hide this by editing css (setting attribute hide)

Comment: I'm still developing on localhost, if you click on the link i've given above, u'll the theme there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open header.php and remove line 96: `<a class="ta-bug" title=" TripAdvisor " href="http://tripadvisor.com"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/TA_bug.gif"></a>`, it will be gone. I cannot speak to the legality of this with certainty, but by my understanding of GPL2.0, you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

The theme is under this license: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html

So I'm not sure it is allowed.

**Edit:** In regards to m0r7if3r's comments, it may or may not be allowed, as I'm not an expert in licenses. If you want to take the chance though, look at the other answer.

Comment: How do you figure?

Comment: "Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies
of this license document, but changing it is not allowed." - Let me add that I'm not an expert in licenses. :)

Comment: No, that means changing the LICENSE is not allowed, the section about modifying the software starts here "You may modify your copy or copies of the Program or any portion of it, thus forming a work based on the Program, and copy and distribute such modifications or work under the terms of Section 1 above, provided that you also meet all of these conditions:"...I think...sounds like it's time for a law.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: I agree, I would participate there! Would be a great resource to have.

Comment: Hey! It looks like it might exist at some point, [it's in area51 right now](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24586/laws-legal-questions) :D

Comment: Cool, just committed to it. Thanks for pointing that out!